# How cmake add_subdirectory works for projects dependency?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I had some problems about cmake build system:
There are may projects in my code like this:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── project1
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
└── project2
    └── CMakeLists.txt
...
```

I want to use add_subdirectory to build all projects,so I write them in top level CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(project1)
add_subdirectory(project2)
```

And there are dependencies between projects ,for example project1 need find project2:

```
# project1/CMakeLists.txt

find_package(project2 REQUIRED)
```

And I will get an error message,because project1 can't find project2.

```
  By not providing "Findproject2.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "project2", but CMake did not find one.
```

All I know is that order won't solve the problem.

So I want to konw how deal with this problem?Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using `find_package`? Just refer to targets defined by earlier subdirectories.

Comment: @Botje Because these projects may created by third party ,such as gtest...